# c# calculation process on arrays like in matlab

Tags: c#, arrays, matlab, math, discrete-mathematics

I want to calculate on two arrays something like multiplication, division, plus-minus operation or sine(array1(i) + array2(i)) etc...
in matlab these are very easy.

for example:
`t1`, `t2` and `t3` are arrays:

```
t1=0:1:100;  
t2=0:1:100;   
t3 = t1.*t2; // the multiplication. that's all in matlab! t3 will be 1, 4, 9, 16,  ....... , 100000.
```

or another one, `t3 = sin( pi*t1 ) / t2`; // etc..

what if I want to do lots of operation on array, Do I need to write code all the time for all operations like this code:

```
Double[] Result_Array = multiplication(array1,array2);

 double[] multiplication(double[] array1, double[] array2)
{
    double[] result = new double[array1.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = array1[i] * array2[i];
    }
    return result;
 }
```

How can I do sinus, cosine, minus, plus, division, minus and divisions .... infinite mathematics-situations with one function?
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use System.Linq

```
public TEntity[] Compute<TEntity>(TEntity[] array, Func<TEntity, TEntity> operation)
{
    return array.Select(operation).ToArray();
}

public TEntity[] Compute<TEntity>(TEntity[] array1, TEntity[] array2, Func<TEntity, TEntity, TEntity> operation)
{
    if (array1.Length != array2.Length)
        throw new ArgumentException();
    return array1.Zip(array2, operation).ToArray();
    // return Enumerable.Range(0, array1.Length).Select(index => operation(array1[index], array2[index])).ToArray();
}
```

And use like this :

```
double[] result1 = Compute(array1, Math.Cos);
double[] result2 = Compute(array1, array2, Math.Log);
double[] result3 = Compute(array1, array2, (value1, value2) => value1 * value2);
```

Comment: it works fine. It seems complicated to me. (I've less knowlage about linq) But I think that's the best answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you'd need is a function that applies a delegate (a reference to a function that works with a one `double`, or two `double` args) to each element, or each pair of elements, from one/two arrays of the same dimension.

E.g.:

```
delegate double UnaryOp(double x);

double[] array_unary_op(double[] arr, UnaryOp op)
{
    double[] result = new double[arr.Length];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        result[i] = op(arr[i]);
    }
    return result;
}
```

with a call in the lines of `apply_unary_op(somearray, Math.Tan)`, or `apply_unary_op(somearray, Math.Exp)`

Comment: Can you give a little example please?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for but you could use [`.Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd267698%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) instead and supply whatever `result` function you want:

```
double[] result = array1.Zip(array2, (first, second) => first * second).ToArray();
```

Or using your second example:

```
double[] result = 
    array1.Zip(array2, (first, second) => Math.Sin(Math.PI * first) / second).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's work for me. But I need to use like:  Double[] result = array1.Zip(array2, (first, second) => first * second);  Are there any way to convert var type to Double[] array type?